# Receive open with chosen file in your website

Tags: google-drive-api

I have created an google app which should enable "open with" application option. 
When users choose to open the file, it will redirect them to my website based on the settings given in manifest.json through web_url.

Now, the question is, once they are redirected to my website. How can i use the selected file ? Will i receive the file in POST method OR will i get the file as an URL which i have to download OR is there any other way that i can use the file to process it further from my website.

Please let me know on this, which i couldn't find in my research in google drive documentation

Answer (score 0):

When the user uses "open with", drive will redirect the user to your app. in the request there is a parameter called "state" which contains the id of the file, the action and the user id.

the action can be open or create. Check this documentation for more details: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open

Comment: Ok, will look into this. Thanks